# TCPDUMP, tcp Flag not changing from Flags [S] to other flag values

Tags: tcp, socket, tcpdump, websocket

I need support understanding these lines.

when i tried to connect to server in a particular port it shows connecting and gives me timeout error.

But in the tcp-dump command the packet flag not changing from [s] to other flags.

Review the below log and provide me the better solution.

```
07:30:42.787417 IP broadband.actcorp.in.44306 > xxx.xx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 416168771, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1731483200 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<.C@./.6fj3.(..d.......;C......r.q..........
g4V@........
07:30:42.788613 IP broadband.actcorp.in.44304 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 288165140, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1731483200 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<..@./...j3.(..d......-........r............
g4V@........
07:30:43.811043 IP broadband.actcorp.in.44306 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 416168771, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1731484225 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<.D@./.6ej3.(..d.......;C......r.m..........
g4ZA........
07:30:43.812304 IP broadband.actcorp.in.44304 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 288165140, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1731484225 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<..@./...j3.(..d......-........r............
g4ZA........
07:30:45.826800 IP broadband.actcorp.in.44306 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 416168771, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1731486240 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<.E@./.6dj3.(..d.......;C......r.e..........
g4b ........
07:30:45.828063 IP broadband.actcorp.in.44304 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 288165140, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1731486240 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<..@./...j3.(..d......-........r............
g4b ........
07:30:49.955119 IP broadband.actcorp.in.44306 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 416168771, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1731490368 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<.F@./.6cj3.(..d.......;C......r.U..........
g4r@........
07:30:49.956179 IP broadband.actcorp.in.44304 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 288165140, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1731490368 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<..@./...j3.(..d......-........r............
g4r@........
07:30:50.425698 IP 192.168.100.4.46835 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 3617736523, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3944752462 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<b.@.@..R..d...d.......GK......9............
. %N........
07:30:51.427297 IP 192.168.100.4.46835 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 3617736523, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3944753464 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<b.@.@..Q..d...d.......GK......9............
. )8........
07:30:53.431409 IP 192.168.100.4.46835 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 3617736523, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3944755468 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<b.@.@..P..d...d.......GK......9............
. 1.........
07:30:57.435466 IP 192.168.100.4.46835 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 3617736523, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3944759472 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<b.@.@..O..d...d.......GK......9..X.........
. @.........
07:30:58.147142 IP broadband.actcorp.in.44306 > xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.5000: Flags [S], seq 416168771, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1731498561 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<.G@./.6bj3.(..d.......;C......r.5..........
g4.A........
```

Answer (score 0):

It means either the remote host doesn't answer to your connection request or the reply tcp SYN-ACK is blocked or is lost.